# Center of a semisimple group and irreducible representations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose that I am over an algebraically closed field of char $0$, and $G$ is a simply connected semisimple group.

For a dominant weight $\lambda$, there is an irreducible representation $W_{\lambda}$ of highest weight $\lambda$.
 The center $Z(G)$ acts by scalars on $W_{\lambda}$.

Is the converse true?  If $g \in G$ acts on $W_{\lambda}$  by scalar multiplication, then $g$ is central? How can I see this?

Sorry if this is a totally obvious question.

EDIT: added simply connected... 
Thanks!

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer, or for any future reader: If you assume your fundamental weight to be regular, then $\mathbb{P}(W_\lambda)$ has a orbit isomorphic to $G/B$ and it is known that $G/Z(G)$ acts faithfully on $G/B$ (here you use semisimple and connected).

Answer (score 6):

If $g$ acts by scalar multiplication, then its image in $\text{GL}(W_{\lambda})$ is central. This need not imply that $g$ itself is central; for example, $G$ could be a product of two simple groups, $W_{\lambda}$ could be an irrep of one of them, and $g$ could live in the other. But it's true if $W_{\lambda}$ is a faithful representation.

Comment: Thanks.. That's what I thought. But I'm trying to interpret this claim: if $W_{\lambda}$ is as above, then this author writes that $g_{1}g_{2}^{-1}$ acts on $W_{\lambda}$ as a scalar implies that $g_{1}g_{2}^{-1}$ is central. Here, $g_{i}$ is in $G$. Please see https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/fbook.pdf page 186 first few lines for reference... Thank you for your input

Comment: @Elliot: it seems the conditions being required on the weight force the representation to be close enough to faithful; did you look at the cited Lemma?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't really understand the proof of the lemma. It's also a little too general for me, I only need the char 0 case. I was hoping that it would be simple enough to work it out by hand, given some facts about highest weight representations of semisimple algebraic groups in char 0..

Comment: An even more terse exposition of this fact shows up in "Complete symmetric varieties" (Procesi, De Concini), where they simply state ..$g_{1}g_{2}^{-1}$ acts by on $W_{\lambda}$ as a scalar. Since $W_{\lambda}$ is irreducible, $g_{1}g_{2}^{-1}$ lies in the center of $G$.. So I thought maybe it would be something obvious, given $W_{\lambda}$. In this exposition, there are no previous lemmas or anything like that. In this exposition, everything is done in char 0. Furthermore, I failed to mention at the outset that $G$ here is simply connected (sorry)